# Query posts for most liked

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get a list of most liked (heart button) posts from my website. Here is the source I am using for this functionality:

https://github.com/JonMasterson/WordPress-Post-Like-System

I am using this query string to pull the posts and order them based on likes. It doesn't seem to be working though.

```
query_posts("meta_key=votes_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&posts_per_page=5" );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks all!

-Ponte

Comment: There is too little information in your question to give us any meaningful overview of your problem. Is your website running on WordPress? Where is the `query_post(...)` logic being implemented? In a plugin? In your theme's `functions.php`? What do you mean by not working? Did you check your network tab (if it is an AJAX request)? Are entries in your database table updated/added?

Comment: Hi Terry. Thanks so much for taking the time to respond. I think I just used the old meta_key. Seems to be working now. I'll post it for others just in case anyone else comes across this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

After changing the meta key to '_post_like_count' it seems to work.

Here is the string for those that run across this and are wondering what changed.

Hope it helps someone! :)

```
query_posts("meta_key=_post_like_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&posts_per_page=5" );
```

Ponte